# Remove negative amount and a corresponding positive amount - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the payments table and it happens that payments could be submitted erroneously, so for my analysis purposes, I need to remove the negated amount and the actual payment (it is the payment submitted prior to the negated amount). However, it is not necessary that the negative amount proceeds the positive one.

Use case 1:
Original table:

[image]

Expected outcome:

[image]

However, I also have the cases like the below when several payments were done erroneously:
Use case 2: Original table. Although, I am almost ready to give up on these use cases.

[image]

Expected outcome:

[image]

I tried to resolve it on the SQL level but it seems to be a daunting task for SQL. All SQL solutions I tried, take the modulus of the amount and then, do several groups on accountid and the abs value, and I feel it is the right direction but then, maybe there is a better way to do it in the Python world.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
    'accountid': ['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2'],
    'amount': [5,5,5,5,-5,5,5,5,-15,5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],
    'accountid': ['1','1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2'],
    'amount': [5,5,5,5,-5,5,5,5,-15,5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
def clean_df(df):
    df = df.copy()
    result = []
    g = df.groupby("accountid")
    
    for _, group in g:
        to_reduce = group[group.amount < 0].amount.abs().sum()
        to_drop = []
        group = group[group.amount > 0]
        for index, row in group[::-1].iterrows():
            if to_reduce > 0:
                if row.amount > to_reduce:
                    # update row in gorup
                    row.amount -= to_reduce
                    group.loc[group.index == index, "amount"] = row.amount
                    to_reduce = 0
                else:
                    to_reduce -= row.amount
                    to_drop.append(index)
            if to_reduce == 0:
                group = group.drop(to_drop)
                result.append(group)
                break
    return pd.concat(result)
```

```
clean_df(df)

# output
    id  accountid   amount
0   1   1   5
1   2   1   5
2   3   1   5
5   6   2   5
```

Case when we have accountid == 2 only:

```
    id  accountid   amount
0   1   2   5
1   2   2   5
2   3   2   5
3   4   2   -15
4   5   2   5


clean_df(df)

# oudput

id  accountid   amount
0   1   2   5
```

Comment: thank you! it got right for the first case but then, for the 2nd, I have a different output than you have i.e. the row with -15 was removed and four rows for accountid2 were returned

Comment: I edited my post to add that case you are talking about. Output seems correct?

Comment: I've updated the original post where I run only 2nd account.

Comment: Ahh sorry I put there `clean_df(df[df.amount > 0])` instead of `clean_df(df)`. I was checking if this still works.

Comment: Testing with the real data

Comment: So, what you did is you, calculated the cumulative sum of all negative values and then, looped through the dataframe starting from the end, comparing the amount value with the cumulative sum and reducing that cumulative amount with the actual amount each time?

Comment: Correct. Grouped separately for each *accountid*.

Comment: question, I've just found the case that when the last value is a way larger than the negative amount, it throws the 'no concatenate' results error. do I need to add the condition to your script when to_reduce<0? data = {
    'id': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
    'accountid': ['1','1','1','1','1'],
    'amount': [5,-5,5,5,20]
}

Comment: I updated *clean_df* function. Test it now, should be working well.

Comment: Pav3k, thank you for the help! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get to your desired outcome by creating two temporary helping columns, and dropping some rows with conditions. Having complicated loops is rarely a good idea in my opinion as `pandas` is well equipped.

Adding two columns, the total amount of each 'accountid', `groupby.sum()` and the cumulative sum of 'amount' column, `groupby.cumsum()`:

```
t = df.groupby('accountid',as_index=False).amount.sum().rename({'amount':'total_amount'},axis=1)
df = pd.merge(df,t,on='accountid',how='left')
df['cumsum_id'] = df.groupby('accountid')['amount'].cumsum()

>>> df
   id accountid  amount  total_amount  cumsum_id
0   1         1       5            15          5
1   2         1       5            15         10
2   3         1       5            15         15
3   4         1       5            15         20
4   5         1      -5            15         15
5   6         2       5             5          5
6   7         2       5             5         10
7   8         2       5             5         15
8   9         2     -15             5          0
9  10         2       5             5          5
```

Then the last step would be to drop the rows where the 'total_amount' of each 'accountid' is greater than or equal to the cumulative sum of each 'accountid', and where the 'amount' col is greater than 0. Lastly, dropping the duplicates:

```
df[(df['total_amount'] >= df['cumsum_id']) & (df['amount'] > (0))].drop_duplicates(subset=['accountid','amount','total_amount','cumsum_id']).drop(['total_amount','cumsum_id'],axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
  id accountid  amount
0  1         1       5
1  2         1       5
2  3         1       5
5  6         2       5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the first case, the second case is not clear to me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

In [54]: df[~np.logical_or(df.amount.lt(0).shift(-1).fillna(False), df.amount.lt(0))]
Out[54]: 
  id accountid  amount
0  1         1       5
1  2         1       5
2  3         1       5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I believe your solution looks at the row right prior to the negative amount row but I should have specified that there could be cases when it is not always the case.

Comment: Please be clear about your requirements in the question.

Comment: Yudhiesh, I've corrected, thank you for pointing out. I've accepted the answer from Pav3K, though because the testing gave the correct results. Thank you for jumping with your help!